# How to process multiple SQL files using SSIS package?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have number of .sql files which I need to execute them in particular order. How can I do this using SSIS package?

Otherwise, I have to execute these scripts manually in sequence.

Comment: Have you tried the Execute SQL Task? Does the content of the files change?

Comment: How is the order of execution defined? Is it based on the filename of the scripts (e.g. script1.sql, script2.sql, script3.sql, ...)? In that case, I would use a Foreach Loop-container, to load the contents of each script into a temporary table with two columns (scriptname, scriptcontent). Once you have the SQL-statements loaded into this table, you could, for example, read the SQL-statements in a Data Flow (sorted by scriptname), and use a OLE DB Command transformation, to execute the script content.

Comment: @twoleggedhorse- I have not used Execute SQL Task. where can I get this option in SQL Server?

Answer (score 2):

SSIS have a component that is "**execute SQL Task**". Make a flow of "execute SQL Task" and voila you have your scripts executed by the right order.